# csplain and url package not working with pdftex

Tags: urls, plain-tex, csplain

MWE (test.tex):

```
\input miniltx
\input url.sty

\url{http://www.google.com}

\bye
```

Commands:

`pdftex -fmt=csplain test.tex` -- fails

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=csplain)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
 encTeX v. Jun. 2004, reencoding enabled.
(./test.tex The format: csplain <Nov. 2013>.
The cs-fonts are preloaded and A4 size implicitly defined.
The utf8->iso8859-2 re-encoding of Czech+Slovak alphabet activated by encTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \warntwobytes 
\do #1#2->\mathcode `#1
                       =32768 \begingroup \lccode `\~`#1\lowercase {\endgrou...

\UrlEncSpecials ...char 27 }\do \warntwobytes ^^df
                                                  {\mathchar 25 }\do \~{\low...

\Url@MathSetup ...ct \UrlSpecials \UrlEncSpecials 
                                                  \let \do \set@mathnolig \v...

\Url@FormatString ->\UrlFont \Url@MathSetup 
                                            $\fam \z@ \textfont \z@ \font \e...

\Url@z ...rcent \Url@HyperHook {\Url@FormatString 
                                                  }\endgroup 
l.4 \url{http://www.google.com}

?
```

`pdftex -fmt=pdfcsplain test.tex` -- fails with similar message

`xetex -fmt=pdfcsplain test.tex` -- succeeds

`luatex -fmt=pdfcsplain test.tex` -- succeeds!

Any thoughts on a fix?

p.s. I am aware of the url support in OPmac, but would like the option of using eplain/url with csplain as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`csplain` is (by default) sensitive to non UTF-8 codes in input. It uses encTeX for this in `pdftex` engine. The `url.sty` manipulates with non UTF-8 codes, encTeX is sensive to this more than we need and this yields this error.

You can write `\input utf8off` at beginning of the document. After this, the `pdftex` treats its input normally as 8bit.

If you are using `pdftex` and you need to keep active UTF-8 input then you can deactivate it only when macro `url.sty` is scanned. This means:

```
\mubytein=0
\input miniltx
\input url.sty
\mubytein=1

\url{http://www.google.com}

\bye
```